# How to idiomatically initialize to zero or increment a property?

Tags: javascript

I love those short js oneliners. I'd like to know if there's something logical and elegant for:

- intializing a variable to zero if undefined
- increment by one otherwise.

Shorter than this preferrably ;)

```
var obj = {} ; 

//some iterative called function
obj.prop = obj.prop===undefined?0:obj.prop++;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increment an object property value if it exists, else set the initial value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690814/how-to-increment-an-object-property-value-if-it-exists-else-set-the-initial-val)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This will result in `NaN` for the first increment, which will default to `0`.

```
obj.prop = ++obj.prop || 0;
```

Comment: Sweet. NAN results in falsy thus the second argument of the lazy-OR is executed. Waiting a minute for some other answers otherwise accepting this.

Comment: @chumkiu: I don't know what you mean. It works with the code in the question.

Comment: @chumkiu yes, because referencing an undeclared variable is an error.  It works if you declare using the `var` keyword first, though - `var a = ++a || 0`.

Comment: @Alnitak: Do you mean an undeclared variable? It'll work just fine for variables that are declared but have an `undefined` value. ...Nevermind, just saw your updated comment.

Comment: @user1689607 yes but it doesn't works with simple `a` variable. The answer say about `variable` (generic). Though the example is a property of object

Comment: @chumkiu: Works fine with a variable, but obviously the variable must exist before you can get its value.

Comment: @user1689607 yes, I meant undeclared, not undefined.

Comment: @user1689607 but If we should initialize it, that's not a "perfect" answer (see the first point of the question). It's just a note, your answer is great anyway :)

Comment: @Alnitak perfect. your solution `var a = ++a || 0` (I've tried without `var`)

Comment: @chumkiu: Well... yes, but I would consider the requirement to be declaration not initialization *(at least not explicit initialization)*. As long as you have `var a;`, it's declared, but not initialized *(by the developer)*.

Comment: Careful. E.g. `obj.prop = ++obj.prop || 99;` but `++obj.prop` evaluates to 0, you'll get `obj.prop == 99`, because of the truthiness of 0 and 99.

Answer (score 43):

A cleaner way of doing this is simply

```
obj.prop = obj.prop + 1 || 0;
```

Using the increment operator is wrong or overkill. The suffixed operator, `x++`, (the example in the question) should not work at all. The prefixed, `++x`, leads to assigning twice (like saying `x = x = x+1`)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why does it hurt to assign twice?

Comment: @CharlesWood Late comment, but you'll be instantly doubling your runtime.  Considering these increment or set to zero lines are generally used in for loops, it's a prime spot for optimisation if 'n' is high, especially if said optimisation also increases ease of reading.

(Edit: On further thought, it might be the case that this gets optimised out by the interpreter, but I wouldn't bet on it.)

Answer (score 5):

This works for both plain JS and TypeScript:

```
obj.prop = (obj.prop ?? 0) + 1;
```

Comment: `(obj.prop ?? 0) + 1` initializes to 1 not 0

Comment: I understood that to be desired. This can be trivially altered in to `(obj.prop ?? -1) + 1` ofc.

Answer (score 3):

To initialise to 1
obj.prop = -~obj.prop

To initialize to 0
~~++obj.prop
OR
++obj.prop | 0

Comment: wow, nice approach! But: 1. it's a brainf*ck to read :)  and 2. it's not correct, it initialises to 1, not 0

Comment: Ha yes that's right, so the shorter i can make is       obj.prop = ~~++obj.prop that is the same as ++obj.prop | 0 where | 0 is like math.floor

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [I Hate Lazy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298232/short-javascript-code-for-initialize-to-zero-or-increment/#13298258) but avoids the double assignment as [Bodgan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298232/short-javascript-code-for-initialize-to-zero-or-increment/#27403831) points out

```
++obj.prop || (obj.prop=0)
```

in the global scope

```
++window.foo || (window.foo=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to directly pass a variable to the function inc(obj.prop), because in javascript variables are passed by value, but you can pass the object itself and the name of the variable you want to increment.

```
Object.prototype.inc = function(n){ this[n]? this[n]++ : this[n] = 1; }

let obj = {};

obj.inc("prop");

// obj.prop == 1
```

You can also add the required fields to the object before

```
Object.prototype.has_fields = function(obj2){
    for(let p of Object.keys(obj2)){
        if(obj2[p].constructor == Object){
            if(!this[p]) this[p] = {};
            this[p].has_fields(obj2[p]);
        }else{
            if(!this[p]) this[p] = obj2[p];
        }
    }
    return this;
}

let obj = {};

    obj.has_fields({a:{b:{c:{d:{prop:0}}}}});
    obj.a.b.c.d.prop++;
    // obj.a.b.c.d.prop == 1

    obj.has_fields({a:{b:{c:{d:{prop:0}}}}});
    obj.a.b.c.d.prop++;
    // obj.a.b.c.d.prop == 2
```

Comment: It's better to write your answer in English.

Comment: write answer in English