# How to increment an object property value if it exists, else set the initial value?

Tags: javascript

How might I add check to see if a key already exists, and if does, increment the value, and if it doesn't exist, then set the initial value?

Something like this pseudo-code:

```
var dict = {};
var new_item = "Bill"

If new_item not in dict:
dict[new_item] = 1

else:

dict[new_item] += 1
```

Comment: May be this? `1 + (dict['item_key'] || 0)`

Comment: `if ('item' in dict)` will tell you if it exists. Look up the `in` operator.

Comment: link to `in` explained here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to idiomatically initialize to zero or increment a property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298232/how-to-idiomatically-initialize-to-zero-or-increment-a-property)

Answer (score 146, accepted):

```
dict[key] = (dict[key] || 0) + 1;
```

Comment: Great! One less lookup compared to `dict[key] = dict[key] ? dict[key]+1 : 1`

Answer (score 25):

@snak's way is pretty clean and the `||` operator makes it obvious in terms of readability, so that's good.

For completeness and trivia there's this bitwise way that's pretty slick too:

```
dict[key] = ~~dict[key] + 1;
```

This works because `~~` will turn many non-number things into `0` after coercing to Number. I know that's not a very complete explanation, but here are the outputs you can expect for some different scenarios:

```
~~(null)
0
~~(undefined)
0
~~(7)
7
~~({})
0
~~("15")
15
```

Comment: very concise, exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 4):

Your pseudo-code is almost identical to the actual code:

```
if (key in object) {
    object[key]++;
} else {
    object[key] = 1;
}
```

Although I usually write:

```
if (!(key in object)) {
    object[key] = 0;
}

object[key]++;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ternary operator (?:) like this:

```
dictionary[key] ? 
    dictionary[key].value += 1 : 
    dictionary[key] = {value: 1};
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check if the object has an own property with the *new_item* name first. If it doesn't, add it and set the value to 1. Otherwise, increment the value:

```
var dict = {};
var new_item = "Bill"

dict[new_item] = dict.hasOwnProperty(new_item)? ++dict[new_item] : 1;
```

The above is a bit wasteful as if the property exists, it increments it, then assigns the new value to itself. A longer but possibly more efficient alternative is if the property doesn't exist, add it with a value of zero, then increment it:

```
if (!dict.hasOwnProperty(new_item)) {
  dict[new_item] = 0;
}
++dict[new_item];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a lot of ways. In general if you want to know if an `Object` has a key you use the `in` modifier with the key name. This looks like:

```
var key = "key name";
var dict = {};
var hasKey = (key in dict);
```

Though you can check if a value is set by simply testing if it is `undefined`. This being that in JavaScript if you don't have a value initialized and send it through an if statement it will act as a false. Which looks like:

```
var dict = {};
if(dict[key]) {
   print("key: " + dict[key]);
} else {
   print("Missing key");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If value exist then (prev value + 1) OR set initial value 1.

```
const obj = {};

addToObj = key =>{
// Using ternary operator
obj[key] = obj[key] ? (obj[key] + 1) : 1;
}

addToObj('alex');
addToObj('adam');
addToObj('maria');
addToObj('maria');
addToObj('alex');
addToObj('john');
addToObj('jack');
addToObj('rock');
console.log(obj);
```