# javascript hashmap one line modify or create

Tags: javascript, hashmap

I want to know if there is a clean way to modify a value in a hashmap or create it if it doesn't exist without doing an if block.  Example of what i'm currently doing

```
let dict = {}
if(dict['key']){
 dict['key'] += 1
} else {
 dict['key'] = 1
}
```

Want to know if there is a cleaner way to do what I did above.

Comment: You could use the ternary operator ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increment an object property value if it exists, else set the initial value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690814/how-to-increment-an-object-property-value-if-it-exists-else-set-the-initial-val)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increment a value in a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39590858/how-to-increment-a-value-in-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 0):

Use dot notation, because the property isn't dynamic, and alternate `dict.key` with 0 before adding 1.

```
dict.key = (dict.key || 0) + 1;
```