# How many times strings from one array exist in another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays, storyWords, and overusedWords. I am trying to get to know, how many times an overusedWords string is in storyWords in an object format. The output should like `{really: 2, very: 5, basically: 1}`, however, at the moment I am getting output like `{really: 1, very: 1, basically: 1}`. It looping only once.

```js
let story = 'Last weekend, I took literally the most beautiful bike ride of my life. The route is called "The 9W to Nyack" ' +
  'and it actually stretches all the way from Riverside Park in Manhattan to South Nyack, New Jersey. It\'s really an adventure ' +
  'from beginning to end! It is a 48 mile loop and it basically took me an entire day. I stopped at Riverbank State Park to take' +
  ' some extremely artsy photos. It was a short stop, though, because I had a really long way left to go. After a quick photo' +
  ' op at the very popular Little Red Lighthouse, I began my trek across the George Washington Bridge into New Jersey.' +
  '  The GW is actually very long - 4,760 feet! I was already very tired by the time I got to the other side.' +
  '  An hour later, I reached Greenbrook Nature Sanctuary, an extremely beautiful park along the coast of the Hudson.' +
  '  Something that was very surprising to me was that near the end of the route you actually cross back into New York!' +
  ' At this point, you are very close to the end.';

let overusedWords = ['really', 'very', 'basically'];

const storyWords = story.split(' ');


const objGroup = storyWords.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => {
  overusedWords.forEach((word) => {
    if (currentValue === word) {
      previousValue[currentValue] += 1;
    } else {
      previousValue[word] = 1;
    }
  })
  return previousValue;
}, {});

console.log(objGroup);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if a `currentValue` is an overused word, and update `previousValue` accordingly:

```
const objGroup = storyWords.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => {
  if (overusedWords.includes(currentValue)) {
    previousValue[currentValue] = (previousValue[currentValue] || 0) + 1;
  }
  return previousValue;
}, {});
```

**Improvement:** create a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) `const overusedWordsSet = new Set(overusedWords);` and check if a word is an overused one using `overusedWordsSet.has(currentValue)`

Comment: // Why this code does not work here, will you please explain?
if (overusedWords.includes(currentValue)) {
      previousValue[currentValue] += 1;
    } else {
      previousValue[currentValue] = 1;
    }
    return previousValue;

Comment: @MamunurRashid you only want to update ``previousValue`` if the ``currentValue`` is in ``overusedWords``. The ``else`` here is saying that if it's not, set it's value as ``1`` which doesn't match with the expected output above. Besides, the ``if`` doesn't check if ``previousValue`` has such a key before incrementing it's value, which results in a ``NaN``.

Answer (score 3):

The default initial value for `previousValue[currentValue]` is `undefined`.

When you try to do math with undefined you get `NaN`. When you try to do more math - `+1` on `NaN` - you just get `NaN` again.

You need to initialize the value to `0`:

```
previousValue[currentValue] = (previousValue[currentValue] || 0) + 1;
```

Alternatively you can initialize that initial value you pass to `storyWords.reduce(...)` with all 0 values:

```
let overusedWords = ['really', 'very', 'basically'];

let initial = overusedWords.reduce((aggreg, oWord) => {
    aggreg[oWord] = 0
    return aggreg
}, {})

initial
```

---

Also, I don't know what that `else {` block is supposed to be doing:

```
    } else {
      previousValue[word] = 1;
    }
```

But it's overwriting all the values to `1`

Comment: Thank you for offering an explanation about the OPs existing code. Related: [How to increment an object property value if it exists, else set the initial value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690814/how-to-increment-an-object-property-value-if-it-exists-else-set-the-initial-val) and [short javascript code for: initialize to zero or increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298232/short-javascript-code-for-initialize-to-zero-or-increment).

Answer (score 2):

Something like the below could work. I made the assumption that you want to count words by ignoring the case, so I added a `toLowerCase()` call on the string comparison when checking strings in the `storyWords` array (`overusedWords` already contains lowercase strings).

```js
const story = 'Last weekend, I took literally the most beautiful bike ride of my life. The route is called "The 9W to Nyack" ' +
    'and it actually stretches all the way from Riverside Park in Manhattan to South Nyack, New Jersey. It\'s really an adventure ' +
    'from beginning to end! It is a 48 mile loop and it basically took me an entire day. I stopped at Riverbank State Park to take' +
    ' some extremely artsy photos. It was a short stop, though, because I had a really long way left to go. After a quick photo' +
    ' op at the very popular Little Red Lighthouse, I began my trek across the George Washington Bridge into New Jersey.' +
    '  The GW is actually very long - 4,760 feet! I was already very tired by the time I got to the other side.' +
    '  An hour later, I reached Greenbrook Nature Sanctuary, an extremely beautiful park along the coast of the Hudson.' +
    '  Something that was very surprising to me was that near the end of the route you actually cross back into New York!' +
    ' At this point, you are very close to the end.';
  
const overusedWords = ['really', 'very', 'basically'];
  
const storyWords = story.split(' ');

const overusedWordCounts = {};

overusedWords.forEach((word) => {
  overusedWordCounts[word] = storyWords.filter(storyWord => storyWord.toLowerCase() === word).length;
});

console.log(overusedWordCounts);
```

Comment: The `.toLowerCase()` seems worthy of an explanation - it's not in the original question. Are there some assumptions you've made about what the question is trying to do, or things the OP has taken for granted?

Comment: Good point. The assumption I made was that the case should be ignored when counting the frequency of words for example `basically` and `Basically` both count.

Comment: Sounds like a good edit for your question!

Answer (score -1):

I think you're approaching this from the wrong side. Try using `.match` to check for occurrences of the word in the string rather than looping through each word.

```js
let story = 'Last weekend, I took literally the most beautiful bike ride of my life. The route is called "The 9W to Nyack" ' +
  'and it actually stretches all the way from Riverside Park in Manhattan to South Nyack, New Jersey. It\'s really an adventure ' +
  'from beginning to end! It is a 48 mile loop and it basically took me an entire day. I stopped at Riverbank State Park to take' +
  ' some extremely artsy photos. It was a short stop, though, because I had a really long way left to go. After a quick photo' +
  ' op at the very popular Little Red Lighthouse, I began my trek across the George Washington Bridge into New Jersey.' +
  '  The GW is actually very long - 4,760 feet! I was already very tired by the time I got to the other side.' +
  '  An hour later, I reached Greenbrook Nature Sanctuary, an extremely beautiful park along the coast of the Hudson.' +
  '  Something that was very surprising to me was that near the end of the route you actually cross back into New York!' +
  ' At this point, you are very close to the end.';

let overusedWords = ['really', 'very', 'basically'];

const objGroup = overusedWords.reduce((carry, word) => {
  const regex = new RegExp(word, 'gi');
  carry[word] = story.match(regex).length;
  return carry;
}, {});

console.log(objGroup);
```

Comment: You need a word boundary in the regex or it will also match on `every` or `ethereally`